# Series Temporais autocorrelação

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Considere o processo estocástico AR (1). Gere uma sequência de variáveis ​​aleatórias 500 e, assumindo c = 3 e phi = {0,5, 0,95, 1}. Faça autocorrelações de 1ª a 3ª ordem (CR). Como gerar essas correlações em R?

```
T=500
e=rnorm(T)
phi1=.5
phi2=.9
phi3=1
c=3
y1=matrix(0,T,1)
y1[1]=e[1]
for(i in 2:T){y1[i]=c+phi1*y1[i-1]+e[i]}
y2=matrix(0,T,1)
y2[1]=e[1]
for(i in 2:T){y2[i]=c+phi2*y2[i-1]+e[i]}
y3=matrix(0,T,1)
y3[1]=e[1]
for(i in 2:T){y3[i]=c+phi3*y3[i-1]+e[i]}
y1[i-1]=lag(y1[i],-1)
y2[i-1]=lag(y2[i],-1)
y3[i-1]=lag(y3[i],-1)
y88=cbind(y1[i],y2[i],y3[i])
y88
lm(y88[,1]~y88[,2])
cor(y1[i],y1[i-1])
```

Quando faço isso a correção apresenta resultado NA. Alguém teria alguma dica?

Comment: Sei que não é o foco, mas você pode usar a função `filter` para gerar os processos AR (entre outros). Eu fiz um resumo dessa função neste [link](http://wilsonfreitas.github.io/posts/perolas-escondidas-do-r-funcao-filter.html).

Answer (score 4):

Utilize a função `acf` do R, ela te faz um gráfico e te retorna todas as correlações seriais até a ordem que você desejar. Se quiser as autocorrelações parciais a função `pacf` ta ai também.

```
# Criando um Grid 1x3 para colocar os gráficos
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

# Calculando as ACF e plotando os gráficos
lagMax <- 10 # Máxima ordem de defasagem das correlações
acfy1 <- acf(y1, main = "Phi 0.50", lag = ordemMax)
acfy2 <- acf(y2, main = "Phi 0.95", lag = ordemMax)
acfy3 <- acf(y3, main = "Phi 1.00", lag = ordemMax)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
# Se você vê os valores das correlações para cada lag  especifico
acfy1          # todos
acfy1[1]       # primeira ordem
acfy1[c(1,3)]  # primeira e terceira ordem

# uma forma mais prática de visualizar tudo é um data frame
# com todas as ACF das suas séries
df <- data.frame(lag = 0:lagMax, y1 = acfy1$acf, y2 = acfy2$acf
                 , y3 = acfy3$acf)
```

Vejamos o data.frame que foi criado:

```
# input
> df

# output
   lag           y1        y2        y3
1    0  1.000000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
2    1  0.481858929 0.8703826 0.9938383
3    2  0.205811504 0.7514128 0.9876520
4    3  0.057031134 0.6475811 0.9815168
5    4  0.057797474 0.5667994 0.9754042
6    5  0.039005187 0.4872700 0.9692915
7    6  0.007567483 0.4150687 0.9631947
8    7  0.003729219 0.3534594 0.9571159
9    8 -0.011893324 0.2982870 0.9510480
10   9 -0.089122429 0.2497955 0.9449967
11  10 -0.093402150 0.2171471 0.9389668
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está selecionando apenas um elemento das séries. Na correlação, por exemplo, o que você tem que fazer é o seguinte -- selecionar todos menos o último e depois todos menos o primeiro.

```
cor(y1[-length(y1)], y1[-1])
[1] 0.5064076

cor(y2[-length(y1)], y2[-1])
[1] 0.9655964

cor(y3[-length(y1)], y3[-1])
[1] 0.9999973
```